# php expression for only lowercase and underscore for email validation

Tags: php, regex, email

I am trying to have users sign up with a desired email. But I dont want them to have to input the `'@domain.com'`, I just want them to input the username, (everything to the left of `'@'` ). Also, how would I go about making sure that the only characters to the left are lowercase letters, numbers and an underscore? Basically if they enter a capital letter, it should lower it. I do know about `strtolower`, but just don't quite know how to implement it in my script. I only want my script to be able to validate one domain, in this example `'domain.com'`

My script needs these fields populated

```
$email = ($_POST['email']);
```

and this checks if it is valid

```
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                echo "You have entered an invalid email. Press back and try again.";
                $db = null;
        exit();
        }
```

So I know I need to do something with the `$email` variable. Sorry am a bit new to php

Comment: you clearly dont know what a valid email address looks likes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Comment: It's really hard to validate an email address without excluding perfectly legitimate addresses. `x@y.za` is *theoretically* a valid address, and until you attempt delivery you won't know for sure.

Comment: I did just state my domain to be 'domain.com' If the user supplies a username, I would like that to to be the LEFT PART OF THE DOMAIN. If you don't have anything to say, Dagon, just buzz off bro. Simple.

Comment: why stop me using my !#$%&'*!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}|~@domain.com as my email address ?

Comment: I have preg_replace for that
$email = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#', '', ($_POST['email']));

Comment: but why the arbitrary rules, why not let users use\create any valid email address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong, as there is a range of characters to the left of the '@' which are valid in email addresses, but this is what you want:

```
$stub = strtolower($_POST['email']);
$email = $stub . "@domain.com";
if ((preg_match("/[^a-z0-9_]/", $stub)) || 
    (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) ) {
    echo "Invalid email....";
    die;
}
```

Comment: Ok this seems to work but it is throwing the wrong error I have. Here is the snippet in my script. when I do input some bad chars, it tells me Error: All fields are required. Press back and try again.

Comment: I tried to figure out why the other code did not work, I tried using exit(); even instead of die; like you use but I guess I'll just have to leave it to the geniuses like you guys and stick to doing what I do better! Thanks a lot!! By the way, I did keep strtolower before the POST in the stub variable :)

Comment: oh, I didn't mean to remove the strtolower :( I'll put it back in for completeness sake.

Answer (score 0):

See the following:

strtolower: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

strpos: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
$email=strtolower($email);
if(strpos($email,'@')){
//Fail
}
```

Then just validate with filter_var as you have specified.

Comment: Ok I think I need to re-explain. I have a signup form, for users to have brand new emails. I only have 1 domain lets say it is 'domain.com'. I would like users to only have to enter lowercase letters, numbers and an underscore. I want no input of the @ symbol or my domain or it constitutes invalid (or I can supply an error message stating the domain is not needed as input). I later use prepared statements to enter it into my database so it is using the POST for this.

Comment: Yes, the above will convert `$email` to lowercase (put the `strtolower` line at the top somewhere), then it doesn't matter if they enter uppercase, PHP is server side so can't prevent what they enter. The `strpos` in this case just looks for the @ symbol and you can enter your failure code where `//Fail` is. To look for multiple characters, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php which supports an array as the needle.

Comment: I see. But how does it know my actual domain? I don't want users to be able to enter any other domain. Somewhere in the script there should be a variable with my domain but I dont know how to fit it in the script.

Comment: Append your domain after the above? You are checking if there is an @ so if they entered a full email address it would have failed there anyway. Programming entails doing things in stages to achieve what you need. You can use the regex (in preg_match) above to look for wanted characters instead of looking for unwanted characters too.

Comment: I wanted to thank everyone else for contributing. kguest delivered the answer I was looking for even though there are many ways in linux/programming to do things. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
$email = strtolower('dsfds_09azZdsf');

if (strlen($email) == strlen(preg_replace('#[^a-z_0-9]#i', '', $email)))
{
    echo 'valid';
}
    else
    {
        echo 'not valid';
    }
```